# MySQL export command

Tags: mysql, export

I have a MySQL db which needs to be exported to a CSV file. Google told me about a lot of examples for doing this, but all the examples are for exporting just a single table.

Could anyone please help with exporting some data in a particular way (given below)?

The database is like this:

artist

- id
- name

album

- id
- name

title

- id
- artist_id <- FK
- album_id <- FK
- name

title has FK fields which point to artist name and album name.

How can do the export so that the output csv file looks like this:

> ---
>
> column1 (artist), column2 (album), column3 (title)
>
> ---
>
> John, The Latest, First Song
>     John, Work in progress, Nice song
>     John, California, Oh SF
>     Luke, My Songs, One Song
>     Luke, My Songs, Two Song
>     Luke, Collected Works, Magnum Opus
>     Tom, My works, I song
>     Tom, My works, II song
>     Tom, My works, III song

TIA.

Comment: which tool you are using to work on mysql?

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning the tool which I would like to use. Ideally it should be mysqldump, or any other std tool which runs from console/shell script on Unix/Linux.

Comment: ok.. why don't you use a db interaction tool to do so? like `SQL yog` or `phpmyadmin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a VIEW and export from there.

Extending Mahesh's query:

```
CREATE VIEW view_example AS 
SELECT artist.name AS artist_name, album.name AS album_name , title.name AS title_name 
FROM artist,album,title 
WHERE artist.id=title.artist_id AND album.id=title.album_id;

SELECT * FROM view_example INTO OUTFILE 'example_output.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I tested this and it works.

Comment: Yep. This is working fine. Can't thank you enough for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case just write a query for that and when output come then export result sheet [image]